# How to make an extra file a dependency of the assembly I build?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-assembly

In Visual Studio 2017 I build a class library assembly. The assembly expects certain external file (an rdlc report) in the same directory, so for the rdlc file in the project I specify "Copy to output directory" = "Copy always", or "copy if newer", and it works: upon build the rdlc file makes its way into the bin folder. But I also want to have rdlc file to become a dependency of the dll, so if I specify the dll as a reference in another application, I want RDLC file to be automatically picked up together with the dll. How to achieve it?
My assembly project is in VB, but it's probably the same in C#.

Comment: vs 2017 is quite old and become no more updates so you should upgrade

Comment: Have you considered distributing the dll as nuget - in this case you can make the file to be a part of the distribution. Alternativrely you can  look into using [resource files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files)

Comment: Have you considered adding the RDLC file as a resource to the Assembly, so it is packaged as one single item instead of two separate ones ?

Comment: Yes, I know about the resources, but having the report file as separate file allows me to easily make changes to the report design without re-building the dll.

Comment: @VadimRapp I posted an answer and shared two ideas, I think they can achieve enough 'Separation' of the file under the premise of implementing dependencies. :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned 'having the report file as separate file', I think there has two ways to achieve your requirement.

For example, there are two projects on my side, VB_dll and VB_usedll:

[image]

## 1, MSBuild way.

Make the .vbproj of VB_usedll like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>VB_usedll</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- Define the path to the PNG file you want to check for -->
    <RequiredRDLCFile>path_to_your_rdlc_file.rdlc</RequiredRDLCFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="VB_dll">
      <HintPath>..\VB_dll\bin\Debug\net6.0\VB_dll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CheckRequiredRdlcFile" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Error Text="Required RDLC file is missing: $(RequiredRDLCFile)" Condition="!Exists('$(RequiredRDLCFile)')" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Result:

[image]

## 2, Code way.

For example, the class in VB_dll like this:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Class1

    Private Shared requiredRdlcPath As String = "C:\path\to\required.rdlc"

    ' Constructor
    Public Sub New()
        If Not File.Exists(requiredRdlcPath) Then
            Throw New FileNotFoundException($"The required RDLC file is not found at {requiredRdlcPath}.")
        End If
    End Sub

    ' Other methods of your class...

End Class
```

And then if you try to instantiate and use some method in it, it will pop out issue when the required RDLC file does not exist:

```
Imports System
Imports VB_dll
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        Dim libraryInstance As New Class1
    End Sub
End Module
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm already doing pretty much that - "required RDLC file not found". I was hoping to find the way to automatically having it picked up together with the dll. For example, this is how .pdb file is picked up when it exists.
But I now followed nbk's suggestion and verified it in VS2022, and it worked without any extra effort (i.e. , rdlc file showed up in the build of the application using the dll) so it looks like it was indeed a bug in Visual Studio that was fixed in a later release of it.